# Adding 120 minutes if date diff is negative in Amazon Redshift

Tags: datetime, amazon-redshift, date-arithmetic

I am grouping times how much it takes for a person to purchase an item, from the session time to purchase time. There are some cases when due to the timezones the purchase time is 120 minutes than it should be, in that case, I want to add 120 minutes and then group it like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN date_diff('minute'::character varying::text, sessions.event_time, sales.event_time) < 0 AND sales.event_time IS NOT NULL THEN '0. 0'::character varying
    WHEN date_diff('minute'::character varying::text, sessions.event_time, sales.event_time) <= 5 AND sales.event_time IS NOT NULL THEN '1. 0-5min'::character varying
    ELSE 'no sale'::character varying
END AS grouped_session_to_sale,
```

And because of the timezone difference of 2 hours I get a lot of `0.0` groups, I need to add 120 minutes to the `sales.event_time`, I tried this:

```
CASE
    WHEN date_diff('minute'::character varying::text, sessions.event_time, sales.event_time) < 0 
    THEN sales.event_time::numeric+120::text
    ELSE sales.event_time
END as sales.event_time,

CASE
    WHEN date_diff('minute'::character varying::text, sessions.event_time, sales.event_time) < 0 AND sales.event_time IS NOT NULL THEN '0. 0'::character varying
    WHEN date_diff('minute'::character varying::text, sessions.event_time, sales.event_time) <= 5 AND sales.event_time IS NOT NULL THEN '1. 0-5min'::character varying
    ELSE 'no sale'::character varying
END AS grouped_session_to_sale
```

But I get an error which is very uninformative:

> SQL Error [500310] [42601]: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "."
> Position: 3346;

How can I achieve such a result?

Comment: **Side-note:** In Redshift, `CHARACTER VARYING` is the same as `TEXT`, so you might as well use `TEXT` since it is shorter. Also, `'minute'::character varying::text` can simply be `minute` and `'0. 0'::character varying` can simply be `'0. 0'`.

Comment: Did you figure out which period (`.`) it is complaining about? Try removing lines until it disappears and you'll find out. It might be the text in quotes (`'0. 0'`).

Comment: That part worked, after I added the logic to increase the number then it stopped working. I am not sure if I can address another table's value in a CASE as I am doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign the output of the first CASE statement to sales.event_time - "END as sales.event_time,".  This implies that you are changing the source data from inside the select.  You could call this output "new_event_time" with no ".".